# How to Install CentOS8 on LVM on Software RAID

Tags: installation, lvm, mdadm, centos8

I'm trying to do something that should in my mind be simple - I've done this plenty of times on other distros, but can't make any headway.

I'm trying to Install CentOS8 on an LVM partition on software raid using 2 x 2TB SSDs which are seen by the OS as /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc.

I could not find a way to build the software raid in the GUI, so I resorted to doing this at the command line.  I created 2  RAID1 devices - a 4gig md0 device (with 0.90 metadata) and the rest of the disk as a second RAID1 device.

I then added LVM on /dev/md1 and created some raw partitions.

Now whenever I attempt an install, I get stuck with a black X windows with a large white pointer.

If I start without the disks installed, the GUI installer boots, but interestingly and confusingly as soon as I insert one of the disks it switches to the black screen with pointer !

How can I go about setting up this kind of install?

Update:  I deleted the LVM settings on the RAID1 arrays and was able to boot into the setup menu.  Unfortunately the installer showed only the 2 raw disks, and as soon as I rescanned the disks I was back to a black screen with arrow.